# Formula for expected number

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, expected-value

Suppose that a rent a car company has 700 cars and the average per rental is 9 days, then we muliply $2.3$ by $700$ in order to find the expected number of bookings per month.

So the expected number of bookings is equal to $700 \cdot \frac{700}{9 \cdot 30} $, right ?

Why does this happen? Could you explain to me the formula?

Comment: Can you elaborate further. Where do you get $2.3$ from?

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan We have that $\frac{700}{9 \cdot 30}=2.59$ and we pick $2.3$ as a bit smaller expection of the formula.

Answer (score 1):

Well, assuming that as soon as one car is returned, the next car is taken, then an approximation of the number of times each car is used per month is $\displaystyle \frac{30}{9}\approx 3.3$.

Multiply $3.3$ times per car, by $700$ cars, to get around $2333$ rentals per month.

Comment: I see... But then what does the formula $\frac{700}{9 \cdot 30} \cdot 700$ describe?

Comment: I'm not sure how the number of cars relates to how often EACH car is checked out. What I would assume is that 30/9 means that if the car is checked out for 9 days.. EACH car checked out about 3.3 times per month.

Comment: now that whole 2.5 --> 2.3 thing makes sense, because the car isn't going to be always checked out, and yhou adjust for that

Comment: Could you explain it further to me why we multiply the number of cars by $\frac{700}{9 \cdot 30}$ ?

Comment: but i don't know why you're dividing by 30? i'm multiplying by 30

Comment: I did so, because I saw that like that we get $2.5$. :/ @SakethMalyala

Comment: $2.3$ is approximately $\frac{3.3}{1.4}$... Do you have an idea hy we could divide by $1.4$ ?